# Are my disks failing and causing high load on linux?

Tags: linux, hardware, software-raid, perfomance

Today I did **apt-get update && apt-get upgrade** on **Linux Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS** server. Everything went fine. Four hours later monitoring tools alerted me that disk I/O is overloaded. I/O wait has reached 10-40% and the system average load went from 1 up to 20 on a 8 core system. Website went completely slow. 
It looks like something isn't fine with disks or hardware, but I'm not too sure. Where should I dig? Any help appreciated.

**uname -a**:

```
Linux p-de-www 3.2.0-77-generic #114-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 17:26:03 UTC 2015 x86_64     x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**top:**

```
    top - 16:19:59 up  1:38,  3 users,  load average: 11.54, 7.46, 5.76
    Tasks: 217 total,   1 running, 216 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
    Cpu(s):  1.3%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 80.9%id, 17.6%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
    Mem:  16126212k total,  4153684k used, 11972528k free,   193392k buffers
    Swap:  8387568k total,        0k used,  8387568k free,  2281864k cached
```

In syslog there are bunch of ACPI Errors.

**/var/log/messages:**

```
root@p-de-www:~# tail -n 100 /var/log/messages
Mar 19 15:51:01 p-de-www kernel: [ 4184.716158] ata1: hard resetting link
Mar 19 15:51:02 p-de-www kernel: [ 4185.763378] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Mar 19 15:51:02 p-de-www kernel: [ 4185.882753] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 15:51:02 p-de-www kernel: [ 4185.882761] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 15:51:02 p-de-www kernel: [ 4185.883514] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 15:51:02 p-de-www kernel: [ 4185.883523] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 15:51:02 p-de-www kernel: [ 4185.883842] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Mar 19 15:51:02 p-de-www kernel: [ 4185.883860] ata1: EH complete
Mar 19 15:52:19 p-de-www kernel: [ 4262.752244] ata1: hard resetting link
Mar 19 15:52:24 p-de-www kernel: [ 4268.109057] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Mar 19 15:52:26 p-de-www kernel: [ 4269.676180] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Mar 19 15:52:26 p-de-www kernel: [ 4269.769475] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 15:52:26 p-de-www kernel: [ 4269.769483] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 15:52:26 p-de-www kernel: [ 4269.770244] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 15:52:26 p-de-www kernel: [ 4269.770251] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 15:52:26 p-de-www kernel: [ 4269.770483] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Mar 19 15:52:26 p-de-www kernel: [ 4269.770496] ata1.00: retrying FLUSH 0xea Emask 0x4
Mar 19 15:52:26 p-de-www kernel: [ 4269.770587] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Mar 19 15:52:26 p-de-www kernel: [ 4269.770604] ata1: EH complete
Mar 19 15:54:39 p-de-www kernel: [ 4402.577394] ata1.00: limiting speed to UDMA/100:PIO4
Mar 19 15:54:39 p-de-www kernel: [ 4402.577557] ata1: hard resetting link
Mar 19 15:54:44 p-de-www kernel: [ 4407.934367] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Mar 19 15:54:49 p-de-www kernel: [ 4412.579786] ata1: hard resetting link
Mar 19 15:54:51 p-de-www kernel: [ 4415.362269] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Mar 19 15:54:51 p-de-www kernel: [ 4415.475792] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 15:54:51 p-de-www kernel: [ 4415.475800] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 15:54:51 p-de-www kernel: [ 4415.476645] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 15:54:51 p-de-www kernel: [ 4415.476653] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 15:54:51 p-de-www kernel: [ 4415.476905] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
Mar 19 15:54:51 p-de-www kernel: [ 4415.476934] ata1: EH complete
Mar 19 15:55:13 p-de-www kernel: [ 4436.542443] ata1: hard resetting link
Mar 19 15:55:15 p-de-www kernel: [ 4438.876963] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Mar 19 15:55:15 p-de-www kernel: [ 4438.959075] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 15:55:15 p-de-www kernel: [ 4438.959084] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 15:55:15 p-de-www kernel: [ 4438.959905] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 15:55:15 p-de-www kernel: [ 4438.959914] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 15:55:15 p-de-www kernel: [ 4438.960212] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
Mar 19 15:55:15 p-de-www kernel: [ 4438.960235] ata1: EH complete
Mar 19 16:17:32 p-de-www kernel: [ 5774.861347] ata1: hard resetting link
Mar 19 16:17:33 p-de-www kernel: [ 5776.132497] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Mar 19 16:17:33 p-de-www kernel: [ 5776.248345] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 16:17:33 p-de-www kernel: [ 5776.248353] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 16:17:33 p-de-www kernel: [ 5776.249163] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 16:17:33 p-de-www kernel: [ 5776.249172] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 16:17:33 p-de-www kernel: [ 5776.249441] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
Mar 19 16:17:33 p-de-www kernel: [ 5776.249445] ata1.00: retrying FLUSH 0xea Emask 0x4
Mar 19 16:17:33 p-de-www kernel: [ 5776.249538] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Mar 19 16:17:33 p-de-www kernel: [ 5776.249547] ata1: EH complete
Mar 19 16:18:34 p-de-www kernel: [ 5836.778503] ata1: hard resetting link
Mar 19 16:18:37 p-de-www kernel: [ 5840.400297] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Mar 19 16:18:37 p-de-www kernel: [ 5840.500401] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 16:18:37 p-de-www kernel: [ 5840.500409] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 16:18:37 p-de-www kernel: [ 5840.501223] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 16:18:37 p-de-www kernel: [ 5840.501231] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 16:18:37 p-de-www kernel: [ 5840.501468] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
Mar 19 16:18:37 p-de-www kernel: [ 5840.501481] ata1.00: retrying FLUSH 0xea Emask 0x4
Mar 19 16:18:37 p-de-www kernel: [ 5840.501589] ata1: EH complete
Mar 19 16:19:38 p-de-www kernel: [ 5900.742501] ata1: hard resetting link
Mar 19 16:19:40 p-de-www kernel: [ 5903.077048] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Mar 19 16:19:40 p-de-www kernel: [ 5903.077537] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 16:19:40 p-de-www kernel: [ 5903.077546] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 16:19:40 p-de-www kernel: [ 5903.078334] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 16:19:40 p-de-www kernel: [ 5903.078342] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 16:19:40 p-de-www kernel: [ 5903.078579] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
Mar 19 16:19:40 p-de-www kernel: [ 5903.078582] ata1.00: retrying FLUSH 0xea Emask 0x4
Mar 19 16:19:40 p-de-www kernel: [ 5903.078679] ata1: EH complete
Mar 19 16:21:24 p-de-www kernel: [ 6006.666736] ata1.00: limiting speed to UDMA/33:PIO4
Mar 19 16:21:24 p-de-www kernel: [ 6006.666867] ata1: hard resetting link
Mar 19 16:21:29 p-de-www kernel: [ 6012.023734] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Mar 19 16:21:34 p-de-www kernel: [ 6016.669145] ata1: hard resetting link
Mar 19 16:21:39 p-de-www kernel: [ 6022.026105] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Mar 19 16:21:44 p-de-www kernel: [ 6026.671575] ata1: hard resetting link
Mar 19 16:21:46 p-de-www kernel: [ 6028.726319] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Mar 19 16:21:46 p-de-www kernel: [ 6028.824829] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 16:21:46 p-de-www kernel: [ 6028.824836] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 16:21:46 p-de-www kernel: [ 6028.825575] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 16:21:46 p-de-www kernel: [ 6028.825579] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 16:21:46 p-de-www kernel: [ 6028.825811] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
Mar 19 16:21:46 p-de-www kernel: [ 6028.825815] ata1.00: retrying FLUSH 0xea Emask 0x4
Mar 19 16:21:46 p-de-www kernel: [ 6028.825918] ata1.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
Mar 19 16:21:46 p-de-www kernel: [ 6028.825925] ata1: EH complete
Mar 19 16:22:07 p-de-www kernel: [ 6049.650737] ata1: hard resetting link
Mar 19 16:22:12 p-de-www kernel: [ 6055.007538] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Mar 19 16:22:17 p-de-www kernel: [ 6059.652963] ata1: hard resetting link
Mar 19 16:22:22 p-de-www kernel: [ 6065.009914] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Mar 19 16:22:23 p-de-www kernel: [ 6065.849433] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Mar 19 16:22:23 p-de-www kernel: [ 6065.978240] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 16:22:23 p-de-www kernel: [ 6065.978248] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 16:22:23 p-de-www kernel: [ 6065.979084] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 16:22:23 p-de-www kernel: [ 6065.979092] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 16:22:23 p-de-www kernel: [ 6065.979403] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
Mar 19 16:22:23 p-de-www kernel: [ 6065.979424] ata1: EH complete
Mar 19 16:22:51 p-de-www kernel: [ 6093.626046] ata1: hard resetting link
Mar 19 16:22:51 p-de-www kernel: [ 6094.113597] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Mar 19 16:22:51 p-de-www kernel: [ 6094.226485] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 16:22:51 p-de-www kernel: [ 6094.226492] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 16:22:51 p-de-www kernel: [ 6094.227269] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
Mar 19 16:22:51 p-de-www kernel: [ 6094.227276] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff880405e726b8), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
Mar 19 16:22:51 p-de-www kernel: [ 6094.227513] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
Mar 19 16:22:51 p-de-www kernel: [ 6094.227541] ata1: EH complete
```

There are 2 disks in software RAID1:

```
root@p-de-www:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      524276 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      8387572 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md3 : active raid1 sdb4[1] sda4[0]
      1847608639 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      1073740664 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

**iotop** looks fine, there are few spikes like these:

```
377 be/3 root        0.00 B/s   82.29 K/s  0.00 %  7.28 % [jbd2/md2-8]
```

Output of **smartctl -a /dev/sda**:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST3000DM001-1CH166
Serial Number:    W1F1YLLX
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 05dd292d0
Firmware Version: CC24
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4
Local Time is:    Thu Mar 19 16:55:48 2015 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  584) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 255) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x3085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   102   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       195880648
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   094   094   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       10
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   087   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       502482545
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   079   079   000    Old_age   Always       -       18486
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       10
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   097   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       197571510318
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   070   061   045    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 27/35)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       877
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   030   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (0 20 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       80
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       80
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       79985175971891
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       32009289003
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       178724571355

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%         5         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Output of **smartctl -a /dev/sdb**:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST3000DM001-1CH166
Serial Number:    W1F1VM8Q
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 05dbdcafe
Firmware Version: CC24
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4
Local Time is:    Thu Mar 19 16:57:57 2015 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  600) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 255) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x3085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   118   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       178849088
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   094   094   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       10
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   087   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       498642529
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   079   079   000    Old_age   Always       -       18467
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       10
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   082   082   000    Old_age   Always       -       18
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   070   062   045    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 26/35)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       876
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   030   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (0 20 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       44448616564768
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       55043480738
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       154979931141

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 18 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 18 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 18168 hours (757 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 a0 7e 17 05  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x05177ea0 = 85425824

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 a0 7e 17 45 00  16d+20:43:03.906  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00  16d+20:43:03.905  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  16d+20:43:03.905  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  16d+20:43:03.905  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 00  16d+20:43:03.905  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 17 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 18168 hours (757 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 a0 7e 17 05  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x05177ea0 = 85425824

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 a0 7e 17 45 00  16d+20:43:01.000  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00  16d+20:43:01.000  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  16d+20:43:01.000  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  16d+20:43:01.000  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 00  16d+20:43:01.000  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 16 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 18168 hours (757 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 a0 7e 17 05  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x05177ea0 = 85425824

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 a0 7e 17 45 00  16d+20:42:58.104  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00  16d+20:42:58.104  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  16d+20:42:58.104  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  16d+20:42:58.104  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 00  16d+20:42:58.104  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 15 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 18168 hours (757 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 a0 7e 17 05  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x05177ea0 = 85425824

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 a0 7e 17 45 00  16d+20:42:55.196  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00  16d+20:42:55.196  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  16d+20:42:55.196  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  16d+20:42:55.196  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 00  16d+20:42:55.196  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 14 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 18168 hours (757 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 a0 7e 17 05  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x05177ea0 = 85425824

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 a0 7e 17 45 00  16d+20:42:52.257  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00  16d+20:42:52.257  SET FEATURES [Reserved for Serial ATA]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  16d+20:42:52.257  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  16d+20:42:52.256  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 00  16d+20:42:52.256  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%         5         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: I would replace the disk triggering those ata1 error messages in the kernel log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't run SMART self test for quite some time. Try running `smartctl -t long <device>`.
It should take few hours and you can see progress in `smartctl -a`:

```
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                    without error or no self-test has ever
                                    been run.
```

If it does not complete without errors like the last one run, when the drives were new:

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%         5         -
```

Just get rid of the drive.

My guess is @kasperd is right. The drive with sata errors/errors in smart log is broken.

btw. relation between high load and broken drives comes from what load measures. load is a number of processes waiting for execution. Process waiting for drive to return data is indeed process waiting for execution.

Comment: The long S.M.A.R.T. test indeed failed on one of the drives. Few days later the drive completely failed aswell. Replaced the drive and now everything is OK.